# Javascript multitimensional array access not working

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to enable a client to edit JS sources and define multi-dimensional arrays in this format:

```
imageArray[0][0][0][0] = 'image000.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][0][1] = 'image0001.jpg';
...
imageArray[1][0][0][0] = 'image1000.jpg';
imageArray[1][0][0][1] = 'image1001.jpg';
```

I made some dynamic matrices so JS does not output errors due to non-initialized arrays and now the client can define the arrays.

The problem is when I try to print some images, for some arrays (sub-arrays) there is a problem.

If you check check this attached document: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58889914/tmp/bt4-forum.html you will see that it prints the wrong image in `alert()`

Do you have idea what the problem is ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Attachment content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/// CONFIG ////
function initArray(maxRows, maxCols)
{
    var imageArray = [];
    for( c= 0; c < maxRows; c++){
        imageArray.push(recurGenCol(1, maxRows, maxCols));
    }
    return imageArray;
}
function recurGenCol(col, maxRows, maxCols)
{
    if(col >= maxCols){
        return "";
    }
    var row_col = [];
    row_col = recurGenCol(col+1, maxRows, maxCols);
    var row_row = [];
    for(k = 0; k < maxRows; k++)
    {
        row_row.push(row_col);
    }
    return row_row;
}
// INIT:
var rows = 10;
var cols = 5;
var imageArray = initArray(rows, cols);

//console.log(imageArray);

// END CONFIG. Start definng array //

//var imageArray = imageArraya;



imageArray[0][0][0][0] = 'image_0_0_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][0][1] = 'image_0_0_0_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][0][2] = 'image_0_0_0_2.jpg';

//console.log( imageArray[0][0][0][1]);


imageArray[0][0][0][3] = 'image_0_0_0_3.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][0][4] = 'image_0_0_0_4.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][1][0] = 'image_0_0_1_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][1][1] = 'image_0_0_1_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][1][2] = 'image_0_0_1_2.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][1][3] = 'image_0_0_1_3.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][2][0] = 'image_0_0_2_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][2][1] = 'image_0_0_2_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][2][2] = 'image_0_0_2_2.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][3] = 'image_0_0_2_3.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][0] = 'image_0_0_3_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][1] = 'image_0_0_3_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][2] = 'image_0_0_3_2.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][3] = 'image_0_0_3_3.jpg';
imageArray[0][1][0][0] = 'image_0_1_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][2][0][0] = 'image_0_2_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][3][0][0] = 'image_0_3_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][3][0][1] = 'image_0_3_0_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][3][0][2] = 'image_0_3_0_2.jpg';
imageArray[0][3][0][3] = 'image_0_3_0_3.jpg';
imageArray[1][0][0][0] = 'image_1_0_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[1][0][0][1] = 'Image_1_0_0_1.jpg';
imageArray[1][0][0][2] = 'image_1_0_0_2.jpg';
imageArray[2][0][0][0] = 'image_2_0_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[2][0][0][1] = 'image_2_0_0_1.jpg';
imageArray[2][0][0][2] = 'image_2_0_0_2.jpg';
imageArray[2][0][0][3] = 'image_2_0_0_3.jpg';
imageArray[2][1][0][0] = 'image_2_1_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[2][1][0][1] = 'image_2_1_0_1.jpg';

//imageArray[6][1][0][1] = 'image_2_1_0_1.jpg';
var img =imageArray[0][0][1][0];

//console.log(log);

alert(img);





</script>
```

Comment: How are you initializing the array?

Comment: hum... 4 dimensions is already quite a lot of it... I know this doesn't help, but you may want to search for other solutions. There are probably simpler and better ways to do what you want. Anyway, a fiddle could help.

Comment: @Bartdude - I know but that's what client require.

Comment: tsss...clients. If that's what he wants and that's a deliberate choice, then he should have the skills to develop it himself. Yeah I knwo, that doesn't help neither :-/

Comment: @Bartdude - And it must work with any number of dimensions. :)

Comment: @vatri please include all relevant code in your question. I shouldn't have to "check attachment" for crucial details.

Comment: So, your getting paid to do this and we are helping you?  Should donate a 5% to stack overflow.   There are many ways this can be done better : a JSON object of the data points and images. Use console.log for your debugging.  Also as a programmer client management for bad ideas is your responsibility  not the clients, if the client could code they would not hire you and do their own 4 x whatever array.

Comment: @alexmac - Thanks for comments. Even in case this is not for client, I am wondering why it's not working... Don't you think this is strange behavior ?

Comment: @RUJordan - I added to code in question.

Answer (score 1):

### [SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/nadec/6/edit?js,output)

This took me some time ... but I enjoyed every second!

```
function initArray(maxRows, maxCols){
  var c = -1, farray = [];
  var recursive = function(array){
    c++;
    for(var r = 0; r < maxRows; r++){ 
      if(c == maxCols) array[r] = '';
      else array[r] = recursive([]);
    }
    c--;
    return array;
  };
  return recursive(farray);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's solution and programmer spirit. ;)
Thanks!

But, I still do not understand why my solution didn't work even if I set it like this:

imageArray[0][0][3][3] = '/image_0_0_2_3.jpg';

it returns me wrong image.

Can you explain me please ?

Comment: you array initialization was not working properly ... I did not analyzed it deeply but my guess is that instead of creating new arrays you were referencing to arrays that were already created. This way when you did this `imageArray[0][0][3][3]` the array at `imageArray[0][0][3]` was a reference to `imageArray[0][0][2]` ... but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I support Rafael's solution. But I wanted to make it clear why the original code doesn't work as expected.

In many programming languages, you can have multiple places in memory point to the same location. Typically this is done with named variables. So here's a simple example...

```
a = b = c = {hello: "there"};
// now a.hello would mean "there",
// so would b.hello and c.hello
c.hello = "bye";
// now, even a.hello would mean "bye";
```

But it doesn't have to be done like this and array indexes can actually behave the same way.

So observe how I have commented your code and added new console logs. What you see is that, in a lot of cases, you are pushing the same object to multiple places. When you do that, changing its value in one place changes it everywhere, because they're just references to the same thing.

```
function initArray () {
    // This is the first point any array ever actually exists...
    var funArray = [];
    console.log('Just created the funArray.');
    for (i= 0; i < 10; i++){
        // Does ten pushes to the funArray with whatever
        // recurGenCol returns...
        funArray.push(recurGenCol(1, 10, 5));
        console.log('Just pushed a single multi-level array to the funArray. None of these reference the same object.');
    }
    // Returns the funArray after those ten pushes...
    return funArray;
}
function recurGenCol(col, maxRows, maxCols){
    var i;
    // Here, col starts at 1 on the first iteration,
    // it then reaches 5 on the fifth iteration,
    // passing the if check, and the function returns
    // to initArray() with an empty string.
    console.log('About to check if col ('+col+') is greater than or equal to 5.');
    if (col >= 5){
    console.log('It was true! Returning to '+arguments.callee.caller.name+' with an empty string.');
        return "";
    }
    var row_col = [];
    //console.log('Just created row_col, brand new, from scratch.');
    row_col = recurGenCol(col+1, 10, 5);
    //console.log('Now row_col is equal to the what recurGenCol returns when it is called with ' + (col + 1) + ' as the first argument.');
    var row_row = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Does ten pushes to row_row with whatever row_col is...
        row_row.push(row_col);
    }
    // Returns back to initArray() with whatever row_row is...
    console.log('Going to return to '+arguments.callee.caller.name+' with row_row.');
    return row_row;
}
// INIT:

var imageArray = initArray();

//console.log(imageArray);

// First level is imageArray,
// Second level is row_row,
// Third level is row_col
imageArray[0][0][0][0] = 'image_0_0_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][0][1] = 'image_0_0_0_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][0][2] = 'image_0_0_0_2.jpg';

//console.log( imageArray[0][0][0][1]);


imageArray[0][0][0][3] = 'image_0_0_0_3.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][0][4] = 'image_0_0_0_4.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][1][0] = 'image_0_0_1_0.jpg';
var img = imageArray[0][0][1][0];
// We expect this to log 'image_0_0_1_0.jpg'
// and it does so
console.log("first: " + img);
imageArray[0][0][1][1] = 'image_0_0_1_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][1][2] = 'image_0_0_1_2.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][1][3] = 'image_0_0_1_3.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][2][0] = 'image_0_0_2_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][2][1] = 'image_0_0_2_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][2][2] = 'image_0_0_2_2.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][3] = 'image_0_0_2_3.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][0] = 'image_0_0_3_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][1] = 'image_0_0_3_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][2] = 'image_0_0_3_2.jpg';
imageArray[0][0][3][3] = 'image_0_0_3_3.jpg';
imageArray[0][1][0][0] = 'image_0_1_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][2][0][0] = 'image_0_2_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][3][0][0] = 'image_0_3_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[0][3][0][1] = 'image_0_3_0_1.jpg';
imageArray[0][3][0][2] = 'image_0_3_0_2.jpg';
imageArray[0][3][0][3] = 'image_0_3_0_3.jpg';
imageArray[1][0][0][0] = 'image_1_0_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[1][0][0][1] = 'Image_1_0_0_1.jpg';
imageArray[1][0][0][2] = 'image_1_0_0_2.jpg';
imageArray[2][0][0][0] = 'image_2_0_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[2][0][0][1] = 'image_2_0_0_1.jpg';
imageArray[2][0][0][2] = 'image_2_0_0_2.jpg';
imageArray[2][0][0][3] = 'image_2_0_0_3.jpg';
imageArray[2][1][0][0] = 'image_2_1_0_0.jpg';
imageArray[2][1][0][1] = 'image_2_1_0_1.jpg';

//imageArray[6][1][0][1] = 'image_2_1_0_1.jpg';
img = imageArray[0][0][1][0];
// We expect this to log 'mage_0_0_1_0.jpg' but it DOESN'T!!!.
console.log("second: " + img);


// Rules that are true:
// - At 1st level, no items are the same object
// - At 2nd and 3rd level, all items within each parent array are the same object
// - At the last level, same-index values are the same object, except if the first level array is different

console.log('Is imageArray[0][0][0][1] the same object as imageArray[0][0][0][2]?');
console.log(imageArray[0][0][0][1] === imageArray[0][0][0][2]);

console.log('Is imageArray[0][0][0][1] the same object as imageArray[0][0][1][1]?');
console.log(imageArray[0][0][0][1] === imageArray[0][0][1][1]);

console.log('Is imageArray[0][0][0][1] the same object as imageArray[0][0][1][2]?');
console.log(imageArray[0][0][0][1] === imageArray[0][0][1][2]);

console.log('Is imageArray[0][0][0][2] the same object as imageArray[0][0][1][2]?');
console.log(imageArray[0][0][0][2] === imageArray[0][0][1][2]);

console.log('Is imageArray[0][0][0][1] the same object as imageArray[0][1][0][1]?');
console.log(imageArray[0][0][0][1] === imageArray[0][1][0][1]);

console.log('Is imageArray[0][0][0][1] the same object as imageArray[1][0][0][1]?');
console.log(imageArray[0][0][0][1] === imageArray[1][0][0][1]);

console.log('Is imageArray[0][0][1] the same object as imageArray[0][0][2]?');
console.log(imageArray[0][0][1] === imageArray[0][0][2]);

console.log('Is imageArray[0][1] the same object as imageArray[0][2]?');
console.log(imageArray[0][1] === imageArray[0][2]);
```